# GoogleDataTransport causes crash

Tags: ios, firebase

I recently updated my app with the latest firebase version. 
After launching the app and leaving it in idle for about 20 seconds, the app crashes and this is what I read from the console:

`[GoogleDataTansport][I-GDT001006] There was an error reading extension bytes from disk: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "Impossible open file “event-2009730023690886256” because there is no file of that type"`

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/1KU30RgluFU

Comment: Tracked at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3747

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I added explicitly "pod 'GoogleDataTransport', '~> 5.0.0'" on my podfile and that's it...

The problem went gone... now, when my app in background, the memory doesn't raise more.